# Lamp how to work with it!

Tags: lamp

I've search on internet but I need some help how to work with lampp ,like I know the folder to save our work is hotdocs but when i do it it give an error message....some as a turtorial or somethink to help me??

Answer (score 0):

It probably gives an error because htdocs is changeable only by root and you are trying to save a file. There are two options, either you save and edit your files as a superuser from the command line or change the permissions for htdocs folder. I prefer the second one, you can google ways to change permissions on a file and find the most suitable one for you.